# CakePHP using sha1 instead of blowfish

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have just installed a new instance of cakephp 2.6 and the problem I am facing is that it by default uses `blowfish` to has passwords on create/edit.

In the `AppController` I have Auth component set up like following:

```
    'Auth'=>array(
                'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
                'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'),
                'authError'=>"You are not authorized to access this page",
                'authorize'=>array('Controller'),       
                'authenticate' => array(
                    'Form' => array(
                        'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                        'passwordHasher' => array(
                            'className' => 'Simple',
                            'hashType' => 'sha1'
                        )
                ))
        )
```

What happens when hash is set to sha1 is that on create it stil hashes it as `blowfish`, but login function does not verify users any longer.

I have erased all `temp` data as well.

How could I fix it so the passwords would always use sha1?

Comment: Are you sure you want to degrade security in such a way? Anyways: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords**

Comment: Yes, I have to do it in this case. If you read my question, I have tried exactly what is in your source. It now uses sha1 for login but not for creation of users.

Comment: "cakephp 1.6" doesnt exist. As for your problem, the configs for "login" (and as such for the authenticate adapters) have absolutely nothing to do with the way you save/store the passwords in your add/edit forms. Unless you use my Passwordable Behavior and a DRY Configure approach of course ;)

Comment: My bad, version is ofcourse 2.6. So is there any other simple way I could configure it to hash passwords with sha1 hash instead of blowfish?

Comment: "_If you read my question, I have tried exactly what is in your source_" Well, that's certainly not in your question, all you are showing here is the Auth component config, not the actual password hashing as in the linked docs.

Comment: @Domas the link that ndm posted has pretty much the sample that you need. In your AppModel's beforeSave(), just set the hasher method to sha1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked as a charm. If you could post it as an answer, it may be hlepful to some in the future.